# Big query "SELECT * EXCEPT"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am learning how to query bigquery (esp STRUCTs and ARRAYs)

I have a table structured as below reference table:
Table Name: Addresses
Name (String), Age(INT, Address (RECORD and REPEATED)
The columns within Address are : address1, address2, city, zipcode

Question:
how do I select all columns except zipcode

I tried querying as follows

```
  SELECT 
  EXCEPT(zipcode)
  FROM Address, UNNEST(address)
```

The above query is retrieving the address record field column twice.

Also, the subsequent select command that runs is as follows

```
SELECT 
Name, 
Age, 
Address
from temp
```

The address should have all columns except zipcode.

Answer (score 0):

If you explode your address array, you need to rebuild it. I'm not expert in SQL, but this code work

```
select name, 
age, 
ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a.address1 as address1, a.address2 as address2, a.city as city)) as address 
from Address, unnest(address) a 
group by name, age
```

You can’t  use `* except` because you need to group by your keys to rebuild your array agg

Answer (score 0):

Consider below  - leaves all columns as is with except of `address` where `zipcode` is removed

```
select * except(address), 
  array(select as struct * except(zipcode) from t.address) address
from Addresses t
```